# Rails string field in model not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
video = Video.find(79)
video.url.sub! "http", "https"
video.save
```

Looking at my server console, when I make this request, I see this:

```
Video Load (48.7ms)  SELECT `videos`.* FROM `videos` WHERE `videos`.`id` = 79 LIMIT 1
(43.3ms)  BEGIN
(46.4ms)  COMMIT
```

Notice, no UPDATE call is being made, even though the `sub` does successfully find a match and make the replacement.

However, doing:

```
video.url = "https://example.com"
video.save
```

I see:

```
(40.6ms)  BEGIN
SQL (41.8ms)  UPDATE `videos` SET `url` = "https://example.com", `updated_at` = '2014-03-18 14:52:22' WHERE `videos`.`id` = 79
(57.8ms)  COMMIT
```

I've been battling with this for endless hours. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 4):

Because you're modifying the string in-place using `sub!`, the `url=` method that Active Record generates for you never gets called, so it has no idea that you've modified it.

You can either use the `video.url = video.url.sub...` approach, or you can use the `attribute_will_change!` method for that specific attribute:

```
video = Video.find(79)
video.url_will_change!
video.url.sub! "http", "https"
video.save
```

Comment: Just in case it's not obvious from what @Dylan is saying, the problem is that when you call `video.url` you create a string object.  That object is completely seperate to the video object.  It's that string object that is changed by `.sub!`.  I would always do this sort of thing as `video.url = video.url.sub("http", "https")`.  `video.url =` is actually calling a method on `video`: namely the `url=` method.  `.url` and `.url=` are both **accessor** methods, ie ways of accessing the underlying data.

Answer (score 3):

There is several ways to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
video = Video.find(79)
video.url = video.url.sub("http", "https")
video.save
# or
video = Video.find(79)
video.update_attributes(url: video.url.sub!("http", "https")) # does not need a save here
```

---

To test and see the changes of a object between updates/saves, you can use the following method:

```
video = Video.find(79)
video.url.sub! "http", "https"
puts video.changes 
# will display changes as the following:
# { url: ['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npvNPORFXpc', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npvNPORFXpc'] }
```

Youtube video: alt-J (∆) - Fitzpleasure (Official Music Video)

Answer (score 0):

This *could* be related to using a method with an exclamation mark. Most methods ending with a `!` have more or less the same issue, that they sometimes return `nil`.

From the [`sub! docs`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-sub-21):

> Returns str if a substitution was performed or nil if no substitution
>   was performed.

Then again, this might not be your problem here.